# Can't install latest nginx version when using debian:jessie

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, apt-get, debian-jessie

I am trying to enable HTTP2 for my nginx and I have his dockerfile where I use `debian:jessie` docker image and I try to install nginx:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
RUN nginx -v
```

Unfortunatelly, when running it, I see `nginx version: nginx/1.6.2` and according to [documentation](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/how-to-enable-http2-in-nginx/) HTTP2 is available on `1.9.5` or newer.

Why does it install `1.6.2` and not newer? And how can I update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Jessie was released in 2015 and should no longer be used in any production system, as all kinds of support ended in 2020.

Usually, Debian does not provide upgraded versions of the packages they use. If you want to use more current packages, use either a more current version of Debian or a distribution with rolling releases

Comment: So to my understanding using Dockerfile I cannot install certain versions of certain packages on certain image such as debian:jessie?

Comment: You can install exaclty those packages within that Dockerfile that are available on a raw Debian system. Using Docker does not change this in any way

Comment: It worked! I replaced it to debian:latest image and 1.18.0 was installed by default. Thank you